# Given two numbers A and B, make them in ration of 3:4 by only adding integer(s) to A or B or to both A and B

Tags: ratio

I have a set of 2 numbers say 365 and 550, I want to make them in ratio say 3:4
I have the option of adding x and y to 365 and 550, with limitation of x and y should always be integer, both or one can be 0 if required. How can I find the minimum value of x and y?

I am trying to solve it as follows:

365:550+y::3:4
=365*4= 3*(550+y),
solving for y is giving the value in decimal, but I need the value in integers only, that means I will need to add something in 365, so that I can get whole numbers. I am not sure how to do that.

Also I can only add numbers and never can subtract, hence the number should be only positive including 0.

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ required to be non-negative?

Comment: No, they cannot be -ve, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  To get $\frac{365+x}{550+y} = \frac{3}{4}$, you must have $4(365+x) = 3(550+y)$.  Since $3$ doesn't divide $4$, it must divide $365+x$, so what is the smallest $x$ producing a multiple of $3$?  Then $y = 4\frac{(365+x)}{3} - 550$.  If it turns out $y < 0$ and you do not allow negative $y$, they you will have to increase $x$ (and therefore $y$) to make $y$ non-negative.

Comment: Eric you hint leaves me blank at the toughest part i.e when y<0. Can you pl. help little further.

Comment: @Ratna : The question allows negative $y$.  I've asked about this, but there has been no clarification.

Comment: Yes, Originally I hadn't mentioned the constraint, but later I edited my question.

Comment: So what's the smallest nonnegative $y$ that makes $550+y$ divisible by $4$?

Comment: X= 49 and Y = 2, Thank you very much, I got the insight. I am not sure it will happen or not, but what will I do when both of them give -ve numbers?

Comment: @Ratna : Notice that increasing one increases the other.  So ask each of them how much they must be increased and how much that increases the other.  Then pick the *larger* pair.  (The smaller pair doesn't have both nonnegative.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the minimum amount to add, then the first whole number (550 + y)/4 is y = 2. 552 * 3/4 = 414. x is therefore 414 - 365 = 49. 414/552 = 3/4.